# UITableViewCell custom reordering controls

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I'm trying to set a custom image for my cell's reordring control, as per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8603359/change-default-icon-for-moving-cells-in-uitableview/8603664#8603664):

```
- (void) setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setEditing: editing animated: animated];

    if (editing)
        for (UIView * view in self.subviews)
            if ([NSStringFromClass([view class]) rangeOfString: @"Reorder"].location != NSNotFound)
                for (UIView * subview in view.subviews)
                    if ([subview isKindOfClass: [UIImageView class]])
                        ((UIImageView *)subview).image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self isSelected] ? @"move-handle-selected.png" : @"move-handle-unselected.png"];
}
```

But the [self isSelected] conditional is always getting ignored so the image is the same for all cells, regardless of their selected state, since the cells are in a reuse queue.

Any idea on how to get a different reordering control for a selected cell?