# How to hide the table editing mode ||| icon

Tags: iphone, ios

im using a table with custom reorder able cells , when setting the cell to editing mode a 3 lines icon appears on the right of the cell.
i need the cell to be order able without displaying the default "dragging" icon;

Answer (score 4):

To hide the reordering icon, set [showsReorderControl](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewCell/showsReorderControl) to NO on your UITableViewCell. If you want reordering to work, you'll have to implement something.

If instead you want to change the reorder icon to something else, see this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8603359/change-default-icon-for-moving-cells-in-uitableview/8603664#8603664).

Comment: When setting showsReorderControl to NO (false), it's not possible to reorder. At least not in iOS 15.