# Customise UITableViewCellEditControl

Tags: ios7, uitableview

Is there an easy way to customise the `UITableViewCellEditControl`. More specific i want to change the images for plus and minus sign.

What i have found so far (http://voidrant.tumblr.com/post/27760918492/customize-uitableviewcell-edit-mode-views) is that i can do it by "searching" the subviews in `layoutSubviews` and replace the image there.

It sounds like a hack, and i am afraid for rejection, so i wandering is there an other way?

I am targeting on `iOS7`

Comment: Here's a thread for editing reordercontrol: 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/19807800/177442