# Modify reorder control icon in table view editing mode

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, editing

I'd like to use a custom color for the hamburger icon that appears in table view editing mode, preferably even use a custom image. I've found this Swift code snippet in an older thread which was in Objective-C originally (to be found here: [Change default icon for moving cells in UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8603359/change-default-icon-for-moving-cells-in-uitableview)):

```
override func setEditing(editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)

    if editing {
        for view in subviews as [UIView] {
            if view.dynamicType.description().rangeOfString("Reorder") != nil {
                for subview in view.subviews as [UIImageView] {
                    if subview.isKindOfClass(UIImageView) {
                        subview.image = UIImage(named: "yourimage.png")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To fit my `TableViewController`, I've changed the line beginning the loop to:
`for view in tableView.subviews as [UIView] {` which seems to work, but the view with the description "Reorder" will not be found. Has this been changed since?

I would have asked in the old thread but due to reputation I am not allowed yet.

Any insight very welcome!

**EDIT**: I could change the images by changing the above code to:

```
override func setEditing(editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)

    if editing {
      for cell in tableView.visibleCells {
        for view in cell.subviews {
          if view.dynamicType.description().rangeOfString("Reorder") != nil {
            for subview in view.subviews as! [UIImageView] {
              if subview.isKindOfClass(UIImageView) {
                subview.image = UIImage(named: "yourimage.png")
                //subview.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20)
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
   }
}
```

There is a bug, however, when scrolling down not all the icons will be changed. some cells will still have the original icon. I guess that has got something to do with the cells being reused. Is there any solution to this?

**EDIT 2**: I fixed the above issue by making sure the same image replacement logic is being executed in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. Also, I'm checking if the image is already changed, as the image would have weird offsets if there had been an image before.

```
override func setEditing(editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
  super.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)

  if editing {
    for cell in tableView.visibleCells {
      setEditingAccessoryView(forCell: cell)
    }
  }
}

func setEditingAccessoryView(forCell cell: UITableViewCell) {
  for view in cell.subviews {
    if view.dynamicType.description().rangeOfString("Reorder") != nil {
      for subview in view.subviews as! [UIImageView] {
        if subview.isKindOfClass(UIImageView) {
          if subview.image != UIImage(named: "yourImage.png") {
            subview.image = UIImage(named: "yourImage.png")
            //subview.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: 20, height: 20)
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
if editing {
  setEditingAccessoryView(forCell: cell)
}
```

Comment: Did you set the proper `accessoryType` in your TVC before setting editing?

Comment: Also, if you have a question, even about an old answer, it is more appropriate to write a new question, as answers should be answers and not queries for a new solution.

Comment: Thanks for your help, sschale! I set up my custom cells programmatically (they aren't much different from common cells, though), I didn't assign an accessoryType yet. Which one should that be? On a side note, the hamburger icons do show up, but somehow that code doesn't find their subview.

Comment: Well if they're showing up then you don't need to worry about that. What I would do is inside of `for view in subviews`, `print(view.dynamicType.description())` to see what you do have.

Comment: Damn, I didn't think of that. I've tried and printed a lot, turns out the reorderControl is a subview of the cells (shouldn't it have been found by the original code anyway?). I could change it by looking for it inside the visibleCells. There is a bug though, pls have a look at my updated post above!

Comment: Is it all working now?

Comment: Yes it does, thanks! If you add to your answer that I should call the complete replacement logic from the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, I'll accept it, so that it can be found faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glad we're getting your issue sorted. For your final issue, I'd suggest that in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` that you explicitly call the replacement logic to force your code to be called each time a cell is displayed.

(As an aside, logging is always a great way to figure out a puzzling issue,)

Comment: Thanks again for helping out, I've found that I had to call the whole same replacement logic from the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` (I've updated my post). I couldn't get it working by just setting `editing = true` as the images would appear by default, and not only when the user activates editing mode. If I'm missing something please correct me, I'd gladly accept your answer! In the meantime, the solution above works, it may not be the most efficient one.

Comment: I think it works fine - you might be able to make it a bit more efficient by not comparing the image, but instead tagging the replacement imageView, and comparing that as it would way cheaper, but that's splitting hairs.