# How do I customize the color of the cell reordering hamburger handle in a UITableView?

Tags: swift, uitableview, uikit

I have a table view and I enabled editing on the table. A handle that I can drag to reorder cells appeared at the end of the cell but it's barely visible due to the background colors I set for my table cells. How can I customize it to have a better i.e. change the color, thickness, size, etc.

[I tried to follow this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35999511/modify-reorder-control-icon-in-table-view-editing-mode)
but it seems old and it changes the icon rather than the color of the default icon.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Quick searching finds this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45967210/change-reorder-controls-color-in-table-view-cell Read through the answers and see if one of those approaches fits your needs.

Comment: @DonMag Thanks! I wasn't aware it was called UITableViewCellReorderControl that could have helped to find a solution for it quickly. 
[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56646864/15690748) worked but the only problem the color of the reorder control of the dragged cell reverts back to default after moving the cell around or clicking on the reorder icon.

Comment: Yep - looks like recent Apple changes means that solution no longer works. Deeper reading - it was probably a bad idea to begin with. Manipulating built-in iOS classes always runs the risk of something changing from version to version. Looks like the only reliable approach is to implement long-press drag-and-drop yourself.

Comment: It would be a good bug to file. If something like that isn't accessible via the code, I think that means in the new world of Dark/Light and semantic colors, it is going to mess up. You might want to even test first party apps in Dark/Light and see if you can make a strong case.