# How to remove the default Edit Icons in each cell in Xamarin iOS

Tags: uitableview, xamarin, xamarin.ios

[image]

How to remove the default Edit Icons in each cell in Xamarin iOS ?
I want the cells to be in Edit Mode always but without the 3lined symbol appearing on the right side of each cell...

Comment: By default it won't work(using straight forward) you need to subclass the UITableViewCell. After changes your customization, the animation is not smooth behaviour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is almost impossible. Here is a [hacky solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8603664/8187800). I converted it from oc to C#.

```
public override void SetEditing(bool editing, bool animated)
{
    base.SetEditing(editing, animated);

    if (editing)
    {
        foreach(var view in this.Subviews)
        {
            if(view.Class.Name is "Reorder")
            {
                foreach (var subview in view.Subviews)
                {
                    ((UIImageView)subview).Image = UIImage.FromFile("yourimage.png");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, the solution may be broken at any time when Apple changes the hierarchy of the cell, so I don't suggest you use this way.